# Android disable "SignalStrength", etc to log in LogCat

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I get too much info on one phone with Android 4.0 in logcat

Much more on all other models.
I get every 1-3 second

> StatusBar.NetworkController SignalStrength wpa_supplicant

Is there way tell android to not log wireless settings every second?
Other phones do not do that.

Comment: What is your purpose? Performance gain?

Comment: I use Eclipse LogCat to monitor. It lists last N lines. Even I filter useful they disappear soon due to the large amount of `SignalStrength` and etc logs. If I log all events to files then I still have to scroll 3 times more then I scroll on other devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those logs, you want to exclude, have distinctive TAG, you can exclude them by using regex like this in Eclipse Logcat:

```
^(?!TAG_TO_EXCLUDE).*$
```

Comment: Thanks But No. I just select TAG. But logged data does not live long in eclipse as full log size is limited and old records are deleted. I wish to configure phone to not log things like that.